# How to conditionally display webpage items depending on a javascript function return

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

I am really new to the web design, however I have to support and improve the existing code. Now I have a static webpage where the HTML code looks somewhat like follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page 1</title>
<style>
.fixed_s{ position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px}
.fixed_0{ position:absolute;left:234px;top:30px}
.fixed_1{ position:absolute;left:134px;top:130px}
.fixed_2{ position:absolute;left:110px;top:60px}
.fixed_3{ position:absolute;left:770px;top:400px}
................................

.fixed_25{ position:absolute;left:810px;top:830px}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ajaxdatas" style="display:none">
</div>
<img class="fixed_s" src="images/big/page1.jpg" alt="line 1" />

<p id="s0" rel="0"><a href="/php-bin/gen.php?data=A-1" class="fixed_0"><img src="images/2/0.png" alt="line 1" title="A1"/></a></p>
<p id="s1" rel="0"><a href="/php-bin/gen.php?data=A-2" class="fixed_1"><img src="images/2/1.png" alt="line 1" title="A2"/></a></p>
<p id="s2" rel="0"><a href="/php-bin/gen.php?data=A-3" class="fixed_2"> <img src="images/2/2.png" alt="line 1" title="A3"/></a></p>
<p id="s3" rel="0"><a href="/whi/sub.html"             class="fixed_3"> <img src="images/2/3.png" alt="line 1" title="SubPage 1"></a></p>
..................................

<p id="s11" rel="0"><a href="/php-bin/switch.php?data=B-1" class="fixed_11"> <img src="images/2/11.png" alt="line 1" title="B1"/></a></p>
<p id="s12" rel="0"><a href="/php-bin/switch.php?data=B-2" class="fixed_12"> <img src="images/2/12.png" alt="line 1" title="B2"/></a></p>
<p id="s13" rel="0"><a href="/php-bin/switch.php?data=B-3" class="fixed_13"> <img src="images/2/13.png" alt="line 1" title="B3"/></a></p>
..................................

</body>
</html>
```

There are a number of items to be displayed in the page, the most of which I skipped replacing with dotted strings since they are all similar. So far it worked fine. Now, however, those items should be displayed conditionally. The condition is an integer value represented by a javascript variable. Let say, this value is a bit code, each bit to be used as an "ON/OFF" switch toggling certain set of above items' display. To be simple, let say the bit 1, if set, should allow items "A*" to be displayed, while bit 2 should do the same to items "B*".
The question is, how to implement this option?
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your related JavaScript code segment, and then explain at what point in that code you aren't getting the result you expect.  You've given us your requirements but haven't explained the problem or error you're encountering.

Comment: Devin, thank you! First of all It's not that I am not getting an expected result. It's that I do not know how to approach the problem - and this is my problem :(
I do not know why the javascript code would be important, but here it is:
var area = 0
var user;

    function get_info( data )
    {
        var d = $(data);

        var ver = d.find("version").text();
        area = d.find("area").text();
        user = d.find("user").text();
    }
The variable to contain the above-described bitcode is "area".

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials out there that demonstrate How To hide/show elements.  Questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to be narrowly defined, with right and wrong answers.  Not open-ended How To type of questions.  To narrowly define your problem, edit your question and add in your JavaScript and describe at what point that code isn't giving you the result you expect.  That may require you to do research to figure out How To show/hide elements, and then make your best attempt at implementing that code for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to have some empty divs in your page like:

```
<div class='conditional'></div>
<div class='conditional'></div>
<div class='conditional'></div>
...
```

Then you can target them in your javscript with:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.conditional');
```

You can have an array of content.

To fill a div with content it would be something like:

```
divs[i].innerHTML = content[i];
```

Emptying it would be like:

```
divs[i].innerHTML = '';
```

To best represent the on/off switches, you'll use an array of booleans (true/false values).